# Duplicate several json documents between _attachments and _design doc

Tags: couchapp

I have a bunch of json-schema documents in my _design doc which are used for validation in `validate_doc_update`.

For my api, I also want to make these documents available to clients as attachments to the _design doc, so I want to have couchapp duplicate files before serialising the doc to upload:

```
/_attachments
    /schema
        /user.json
        /post.json
    ...
/schema
    /user.json
    /post.json
```

From looking around the web for a solution to this, it seems like its something a lot of people want to do, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you do this manually, i.e. instead of running your ordinary push command you could do something like `rsync schema/* _attachments/schema/ && couchapp push <host>`.

However, please note that the couchapp tool is deprecated. You might want to have a look at [kanso](http://kan.so) or [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised that couchapp was deprecated, I had looked a little at kanso and did see it had support for addons which might be able to do this kind of thing.

Comment: It looks like kanso does this as I want through the attachments package.